# RcppArmadillo and shed_col()

Tags: r, rcpp

I am trying to remove some columns from an `arma::mat` object using Armadillo. It seems like `.shed_col()` is the perfect way to do that (see e.g. [here](http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html#Col)).

However, the following code does not compile:

```
#include <RcppArmadillo.h>
#include <Rcpp.h>

// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppArmadillo)]]
using namespace Rcpp;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
arma::mat test(arma::mat x){  

  arma::mat y = x.shed_col(0);

  return(y);

}
```

The line where y pops up for the first time returns:

```
conversion from 'void' to non-scalar type 'arma::mat {aka arma::mat<double>}' requested
```

It seems that the reason is that a function involved in here returns `void` while I want `arma::mat` to be returned. Is that correct? Any fixes for that? Thanks!

Comment: The armadillo help page you link to seems to indicate that you do not need to assign the result. So try with the function body `x.shed_col(0);
  return(x);`

Comment: Works like a charm! That was a foreseeable mistake from my side. If you add it as answer, I can accept it.

Comment: Actually yes, perfect duplicate. Didn't find it because I didn't search for `shed_row()` as well. Flagged it as duplicate.